# I have a syntax error, unexpected '::'

Tags: php

An amazing thing:

```
Class Myclass{

 protected $_value = 'content';

 public function action(){

  $this->_value::mymethod();
 }

}
```

=> I've got an error:

> syntax error, unexpected '::'

If I modify like this, it works:

```
$myvalue = $this->_value;
$myvalue::mymethod();
```

Do you know why??

Comment: '::' is for calling static methods so you are calling a static method of a string...which is wrong...

Comment: _value, I think here underscore is creating problem

Comment: @KA_lin I think `'content'` is just a placeholder for the actual content. Otherwise his code `$myvalue::mymethod()` wouldn't work either, which it does according to the question.

Comment: @user3778717: Please provide the full code

Comment: @DWX why would an underscore be a problem?

Comment: Guys, this *is* the full code. The "modified" version indeed works, as it's supposed to. This actually is a valid question! The end result is to statically call `mymethod` on the `content` class.

Comment: Why are you doing this, what do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: Fatal error: Class '_value' not found, works great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling static method from object array variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519272/calling-static-method-from-object-array-variable)

Answer (score 3):

PHP cannot confidently determine what you are trying to accomplish with

`$this->_value::mymethod();`

It can be read as either

`{$this->_value}::mymethod()` (what you expect it to be)

or

`$this->{_value::mymethod()}`.

So instead of guessing and might be wrong, it generates an error. Just use the way around it that you already discovered.

Comment: Well, I've tried as suggested : {$this->_value}::mymethod(); I suppose you force priority to accomplish it. But I have another errot message: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Hehe, the way you did it was the only way that works (at this point). I just used the brackets to indicate the priority, sorry about the confusion.