# :: does not work for static methods when model class is loaded - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consider below code, Iam using codeigniter 3.0

```
Xmodel.php
---------------------
class Xmodel {
    public static function get(){

    }
}

Ymodel.php
------------------------
class Ymodel(){
    public function run(){
         $this->load->model('XModel', 'x');
         $this->x::get(); // syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
         $this->x->get(); // works as expected
    }
}
```

I have a doubt if `get()` is a static method then why it is not working with `::` operator. As a reference [What does this mean? "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966010/what-does-this-mean-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotay) In this question also the method is static but they did not justify why they used `->` for static method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/whats-the-difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Ymodel(){
     public function run(){
         $this->load->model('XModel', 'x');
         $a = $this->x; // save to a var
         $a::get(); // works as expected
     }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520244/3205479 This saved me. Hope some one do not suffer again with this kind of php bug.